# EXECUTESQL error

Tags: sql-server-2008, sp-executesql

Here is the following piece of code that I am trying to execute on SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    CREATE PROC [dbo].[Trend]
    @slsID NVARCHAR(20)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @BeginningRange varchar(20),
    @EndingRange varchar(20)
    SET @EndingRange = ''12*13''
    SET @BeginningRange = ''12*02''
    ;WITH CTE1 AS(
             SELECT 
             dbo.Field1,dbo.Field2,dbo.Field3
             FROM dbo.Table1 join dbo.Table2 where...conditions
             weekNum BETWEEN (@BeginningRange) AND (@EndingRange)
                 )
    SELECT * FROM CTE1 
    UNPIVOT
      ( numbers for type in (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
      ) as p PIVOT
      (
      Sum(numbers) for
      WeekNum in ([12*02],[12*03],[12*04],[12*05],[12*06],[12*07],[12*08],[12*09],[12*10],                                                         [12*11],[12*12],[12*13])
      ) as q
      END
'
    EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @STRING
```

When I try to run this, it errors out saying that

> "Incorrect syntax near the keywor 'as'"

I took this code out and executed it separately and it didn't error out. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does the code you're running have `...conditions` in it still, or did you change those for posting here? Also if you want `@EndingRange` to be evaluated as 12*13, you shouldn't put it in quotes.

Comment: I already factored in for the quotes. This is a direct copy paste from what I am trying to run and Yes, the ...conditions has been put intentionally for the sake of posting.

Comment: Why aer you not just running the code? I see no reason why it would need to be dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like missing parentheses around the parameter to the procedure.

One trick you can use is the print out the sql statement and then try to run that - the error message might give you more info

```
print @STRING
```

Comment: I already did that and I cant find any place where I may be missing out a parentheses..otherwise, this would'nt have executed at all without the SP_EXECUTESQL

Comment: Parentheses are not required around the parameter list.

Comment: Oh - I always use parentheses - I guess I mistook a coding standard for a syntax requirement :)

Comment: when you run the text without the SP_EXECUTESQL, does it give you a line number for the error?

Comment: Like I said, when I run the procedure without the single quotes and SP_EXECUTESQL, it does not error out and completes successfully. Its only when I am trying to create the proc through EXECUTESQL, it errors out.

Comment: Really  use Print - it is the only way to see what SQL is actually going to be executed.

Comment: Thank you all. The problem has been resolved. The problem with the code was that the single quotes were getting replaced as well. Also on the IN clause for Pivot statement, the brackets were completely off the hook. Thank you all for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT and UNPIVOT clauses each require two closing parentheses.

`UNPIVOT (... FOR ... IN (...)` **`)`** `AS ...`

`PIVOT (... FOR ... IN (...)` **`)`** `AS ...`

Comment: I've updated my answer to show both places where closing paras are required.

Comment: I added the closing parans and now it gives me an error on a different line. I will try to debug it as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
where...conditions
```

This won't pass a syntax check. If you have removed the actual conditions it may be that this is where your error is. And:

```
dbo.Table1 join dbo.Table2
```

has no ON clause

I saw both of these by doing a syntax check on the results of print @string which is the first step you should have taken to find the issue. I still say that based on what you gave us there is no reason at all to use dynamic SQl and it is a poor practice to use dynamic SQL if you don't need it.